# How can I load data on a page based on this being added into the URL #a=1380369&i=23007472

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

On a php page with javascript (jquery) in the urel I would like to have something like this
idex.php?var=something**#a=1380369&i=23007472**

The page will load photos and have a next and previous link, when this is clicked on it will use ajax to load the new image into the page but I need to also change the URL to add someting like this to the end of it **#a=1380369&i=23007472** and then everytime a new photo is loaded it will change the URL value.  If a user were to copy and paste the URL of an image page the page needs to use the **#a=1380369&i=23007472** values to load the correct image on that page.

The result I am trying to get is it will act like a regualr galler, you can use ajax to load new photo page but it will not be an actual redirect to a new page load, ajax will just pull what it needs.  The part I need to know is how to access the **#a=1380369&i=23007472** url data and load the appropriate stuff based on it.

Comment: I voted this as spam because I'm certain you've asked this question before; but I was mistaken, it's different from your previous ones. I can't retract the vote, so I leave this comment instead. Getting the querystring in JavaScript should be pretty trivial (`window.location` i think) and then just split it appropriately.

Comment: Regarding "#a=1380369&i=23007472" - it's not a legal URI fragment because of the "&" and "=". SEE 2.3 in ftp://ftp.isi.edu/in-notes/rfc2396.txt and http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2 and 4th paragraph of http://deletethis.net/dave/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcerealnumber.livejournal.com%2F28211.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `document.location.hash`, which returns this part of the URL.

Comment: One could look at the way SammyJS uses this technique combined with change detection in `Sammy.HashLocationProxy`: http://github.com/quirkey/sammy/blob/master/lib/sammy.js#L154